# Getting an error while building socket from Localhost to google.com

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am running a socket programming in java where I am facing issues with this code as shown below to make socket connection between my localhost and google.com but getting following error. I am not sure what's wrong in the code.

```
If I am using LocalHost address as
String x = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString(); 
then its running fine.

//code

public class SocketConnection {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SocketConnection tl= new SocketConnection();
    tl.connect();

}


public void connect()
{

    try {
        String x = Inet4Address.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress().toString();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(x);
        System.out.println(addr);
        Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80, addr , 59645);
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
/127.0.0.1
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Can't assign requested address
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
at SocketConnection.connect(SocketConnection.java:36)
at SocketConnection.main(SocketConnection.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 1):

"localhost" is a special dummy interface that **only** connects the machine to itself. You can't initiate a connection to `google.com` through it. If you want to initiate a connection to `google.com`, you have to do it from an interface that's actually connected to the Internet somehow.

If you replace `Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80, addr, 59645);` with `Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);`, you should be able to open that socket using the operating system's default interface for that destination, but then the source port will be randomly selected.

If you want to control the source port, you can do this:
`Socket socket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 59645);`

Comment: I have build a socket connection between my server to 20 other  clients both residing on my laptop (can be considered as multi client server)  where I am trying to make all my clients to connect to google server at port 80 on receiving a message from the Server. The message from the Server would be connect all - google.com , 80 . When I made a socket connection between my server and client it provided 127.0.0.1 IP address to all my clients with different port number. That's why I am trying to use localhost IP address with the assigned port number.

Comment: @AnuvratTiku Your server provided the clients with the address `127.0.0.1` because you connected the clients to the server over that address. You still can't connect from `127.0.0.1` to anywhere besides your computer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to build does not make sense from the networking perspective.

The remote hostname and port are OK.  The problem is that the IP address your are providing as the source address is the loopback address.  It means "this host".  It cannot be routed to from outside of your machine.  (Or more accurately, if the "google.com" host did send a packet to "127.0.0.1", it would be talking to itself!)

You need to provide the IP address that corresponds to a NIC that will send packets off your host.  A simple way to do this is to change this:

```
    String x = Inet4Address.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress().toString();
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(x);
```

to this:

```
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

Or simpler still, don't specify a source address and port when creating the socket.  Let the OS sort it out.

---

<sup>If you really needed to, you could use the `NetworkInterface` class ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html)) to enumerate all of your system's configured network interfaces, and try pick a suitable one based on the properties of their bound IP addresses.  However, to do this reliably you need knowledge of your network topology / routing, and I don't think there is a way to obtain that information.  If, for some reason, the `getLocalHost` call returns the wrong IP address, it would be simpler to configure the right one via a property, a command-line argument or something like that.</sup>

Comment: I have build a socket connection between my server to 20 other clients both residing on my laptop (can be considered as multi client server) where I am trying to make all my clients to connect to google server at port 80 on receiving a message from the Server. The message from the Server would be connect all - google.com , 80 . When I made a socket connection between my server and client it provided 127.0.0.1 IP address to all my clients with different port number. That's why I am trying to use localhost IP address with the assigned port number.

Comment: Whatever your reason / reasoning, a loopback address will not work as the source address when you are talking to an off-machine address.